# Function call w/ Pure Function & Variables (that are defined within the following module)

Tags: function-construction

Edited:

I have yet to figure out how to solve this problem after many attempts so thanks for the support.

One of the parameters of my function call is itself a function consisting of variables that are later defined within a Module and slots `(#)` for use as a pure function.  The complexity of the problem I believe is due to the unique nature of module defining of variables / functions (`con` when defined by the module is actually `con$134…`) so that the variable defined in the passed function no longer matches the variables they are supposed to reference as defined in the Module.  While it might be possible to use a `Block[]` instead of `Moduel[]` due to the scope, multi-layered nesting, and other factors, I am concerned about collisions.

A short example:

```
SomeFunc[a_, b_, ..., func_:( -con # / Norm[#]^3)] := Module[{..., con = 123}, 
    newFunc = Evaluate[func]&;
    ...
]
```

(`func_` can contain any defined variables of Module with multiple slots `#`)

I know Evaluate isn't correct but just trying to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

ps.  While I have never actually posted here I have used stack very frequently and much appreciate all the support of other posts.  If some has a link to a similar problem/solution I would love it since I haven't found any that either fits my problem or I just haven't realized did.
Thanks to J.M. for the help.

Post:
I have found a solution (it works for my case although not ideal) Because I have some control of the input and can alter before I ever pass it in:

```
SomeFunct[... func_:"- con$ # / Norm[#]^3 &"] := Module[
   {..., con = 123, mod = "$" <> ToString[$ModuleNumber]},
   newFunc = ToExpression[StringReplace[func, "$" → mod]];
   ...
]
    (* newFunc = - con$1352 # / Norm[#]^3 & *)
    (* newFunc[x] → - 123 x / Norm[x]^3 *)
```

Comment: You can use `With[]` for injecting parameters into a pure function: `SomeFunc[a_, b_, (* stuff *) func_: Automatic] := Module[{(* stuff *) newFunc, con = 123}, newFunc = If[func === Automatic, With[{con = con}, -con #/Norm[#]^3 &], func]; (* stuff *)]`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in at least this form won't won't solve my issue (really wish my code was small enough to just write for each case).  The problem being that the form of func will differ but with each one reference local variables & a pure function, therefore I can't define for the single case and so (as far as I can tell testing) the With effective never replaces the variables of the function.  Also since you are defining the full function within the With[] which is already nested within the module it is equivalent of:
    If[func === Automatic, -con #/Norm[#]^3 &, func]

Comment: I have also tried it passing as a string and: Update[ToExpression[func]] but it tosses me an error of expecting a symbol.  Because of coloring I am guessing it is recognizing con as a reference but the scoping of con within the module is resulting in variable mismatch. (con$123... within module (guessing)).  I might be able to change Module to Block but there is enough other activity going on in the code and calls to the code that I do not wan't to risk it.

Comment: Which now that I think about it is probably why I am heaving such an issue with all solutions I have tried (the unique scope of the module variables vs the variable names I am passing)

Comment: You might then consider rewriting your question to have a more representative, yet still simple example.